# Why can't I create a method that 'for / in' loops through the values within that same object?

Tags: javascript, methods, javascript-objects

Can anyone explain why the sum and mul functions aren't working in the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/jcq5010/xdvwh9s4/

I know I can just return this.v1 + this.v2, and this.v1 * this.v2, but I was hoping to write it flexible enough to handle any number of new properties and values that are created in read().

This is for a challenge question in javascript.info.  The flexibility isn't part of the question, but I was curious if it was possible.

```
  read() {
    this.v1 = parseInt(prompt('Please give a value:'));
    this.v2 = parseInt(prompt('Please give another value:'))
  },

  sum() {
      let result = 0;
      for(let prop in calculator){
        result += this.prop
      };
      return result
  },

    mul() {
        let result = 0;
        for(let prop in calculator){ 
         result *= this.prop
      };
        return result
  },
};

calculator.read();
alert( calculator.sum() );
alert( calculator.mul() );
```

calculator.read() should add properties v1 and v2, with each having a value given through prompt

alert( calculator.sum() ); should alert with the sum of the values of v1 and v2 (+ any others created in read()

alert( calculator.mul() ); should alert with the product of the values of v1 and v2 (+ any others created in read()

Comment: `this.prop` is undefined ... you want `this[prop]` and you also want to exclude `sum`, `mul`, and `read` props from your calculations

Comment: also, starting result = 0 in `mul` guarantees a zero result (once you fix your issues)

Comment: The code is reading the user-input into `this.v1` and `this.v2` why would you expect it to be in `calculator` (which is not defined in this scope) ?

Comment: @alfasin - the magic of `this` :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

1. `this.prop` is undefined - you want `this[prop]`
2. your for/in loops will also enumerate `sum`, `mul` and `read`
3. your `mul` function starts with `0` so will always result in `0`

One way to fix it is to test the properties to see if they are `sum`, `mul` or `read` and ignore them in the loop

But there's an easier way, using [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) - the default `enumerable` property of a property created this way is false - so it won't end up in your for in loop

Note, I've hardcoded the inputs and console.log the output because `prompt` and `alert` are annoying

```js
let calculator = {};
Object.defineProperties(calculator, {
    read: {
        value: function() {
            this.v1 = 12;
            this.v2 = 13;
        },
    },
    sum: {
        value: function() {
            let result = 0;
            for(let prop in this){
                result += this[prop];
            }
            return result;
        }
    },
    mul: {
        value: function() {
            let result = 1;
            for(let prop in this){
                result *= this[prop];
            }
            return result
        }
    }
});
calculator.read();
console.log( calculator.sum() );
console.log( calculator.mul() );
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm embarrassed to have missed the multiply by 0 issue.  For the 2nd issue, that makes a lot of sense.  I'm just starting my JS journey but I should have caught that the functions created in calculator are actually methods and are stored as properties when called on.  My solution to this would have been checking if a prop contains a number, and only then running computations on it.  For the 1st issue, I'm not understanding why I can create a method inside calculator that simply returns 'this.v1 + this.v2', but if I instead loop through the values I need to use this[prop].

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, I left a comment below it.  To add to my comment, I don't understand why these first 2 solutions work, but not the 3rd (where I copy the first solution but use '[]' notation instead of '.' notation to access the values:

WORKS:

```
let calculator = {
  read() {
        this.v1 = 12;
      this.v2 = 13;
  },

  sum() {
      let result = 0;
      for(let prop in this){
        if(typeof this[prop] == 'number'){
            result += this[prop]
        }
      }
      return result   
  },

    mul() {
        let result = 1;
        for(let prop in this){ 
        if(typeof this[prop] == 'number'){
                result *= this[prop]
        }
      }
        return result
  },
};

calculator.read();
console.log( calculator.sum() );
console.log( calculator.mul() );
```

WORKS:

```
let calculator = {
  read() {
        this.v1 = 12;
      this.v2 = 13;
  },

  sum() {
      return this.v1 + this.v2   
  },

    mul() {
            return this.v1 * this.v2
  },
};

calculator.read();
console.log( calculator.sum() );
console.log( calculator.mul() );
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
let calculator = {
  read() {
        this.v1 = 12;
      this.v2 = 13;
  },

  sum() {
      let result = 0;
      for(let prop in this){
        if(typeof this.prop == 'number'){
            result += this.prop
        }
      }
      return result   
  },

    mul() {
        let result = 1;
        for(let prop in this){ 
        if(typeof this.prop == 'number'){
                result *= this.prop
        }
      }
        return result
  },
};

calculator.read();
console.log( calculator.sum() );
console.log( calculator.mul() );
```

Are there specific scenarios to use this.prop and specific scenarios to use this[prop]?

Thanks!